# snapd has always failed for me

Tags: 16.04, snap

Apparently `snapd` has no resume support like `apt`

```
android@android:~$ sudo snap install notes
26.09 MB / 64.75 MB [===========>____________________] 40.30 % 21.95 KB/s 30m3s

error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "ubuntu-core" from channel "stable" (unexpected EOF)

android@android:~$ sudo snap install notes
239.43 KB / 64.75 MB [________________________________] 0.36 % 33.21 KB/s 33m9s^C
android@android:~$ pgrep snapd
13599
```

And I have just stooped trying for it again because it always ***EOF*** at the middle

and can someone explain me this.....

```
    android@android:~$ pgrep snapd
    31604
    android@android:~$ sudo kill -KILL $(pgrep snapd)
    android@android:~$ pgrep snapd
    android@android:~$ sudo snap install notes
    error: cannot install "notes": snap "ubuntu-core" has changes in progress
    android@android:~$ pgrep snapd
    31628
```